# Erro em sub-consulta MySql no Workbench

Tags: sql, mysql

Bom dia! O meu código de `SQL` está a dar o seguinte erro:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row    0.000 sec

O código é o seguinte:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y') AS ano, COUNT(*) AS Proposta,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposta WHERE nestado = 7 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y')) AS Adquiridas,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposta WHERE nestado IN(2,8) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y')) AS Nao_Adquiridas,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposta WHERE nestado IN(1,3,5,6) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y')) AS Em_Aquisicao
FROM proposta
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y')
```

Penso que o erro está neste `SELECT`:

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proposta WHERE nestado IN(1,3,5,6) GROUP BY
>   DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(data), '%Y')

Já fiz testes e é este `SELECT` o único que retoma mais do que 1 linha! Como resolvo este erro?

Comment: está agrupando por ano da data, não retorna mais de um pq tem mais de um ano na tabela? já tentou limitar um ano para testar?

Comment: Talvez dando apelidos à sua tabela proposta e nos subselects restringir o ano para que seja igual ao do select mais externo.

Comment: Boa tarde Ricardo! Acontece que se eu limitar apenas para 1 ano dá! mas o meu objetivo não é limitar 1 ano.

Comment: Boa tarde anonimo! No caso que eu tenho, o código vai executar primeiro os selects que estão dentro do select principal! ou seja, eu não posso colocar "AS ano" no select principal para depois colocar "ano" nos selects secundários!

Comment: Veja: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html

Comment: @anonimo! era isso que eu precisava! agora fiquei a entender! obrigado!